# Как в 2D игре проверить, наехал ли один предмет на другой?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу создать 2D игру с поездами. Хочу, чтобы поезд, подъезжая к семафору проверял, в каком положении семафор и в зависимости от этого останавливался или продолжал движение. Как это реализовать?

Так же если кто знает, как сделать, чтобы следовал поезд по рельсам.

Comment: Прошу прощения за грамматические ошибки, не оббесудьте

Answer (score 1):

Ну если рельсы из тайловых элементов симметрично квадратных, то центр спрайта можно использовать как waypoint, либо свои точки расставлять.

Система таких watpoints(точек)  будет дорогой для поезда.

Waypoint можно сделать как позиция и булево значение(помечать, что дорога дальше не доступна)
Семафор можно связать с одной из таких точек, и менять булево значение в зависимости от своего состояния.

В итоге поезд подьезжая к каждому waypoint проверяет, что эта булево значение false, то едет дальше, иначе останавливается и ждет, когда она снова станет false.

Если нужны ветвления на рельсах, чтобы ехал в одном случае по одним рельсам, в другом по другим. То  систему waypoints нужно разбить на lines(линии). Начинает и заканчивается такая линия в точках ветвления, линия имеет систему waypoints, список других линий, на которые он может переехать, может содержать скорость допустимую для поезда на этой линии, и.т.д

Насчет наехал один предмет на другой, либо использовать коллайдеры с триггерами. Либо считать расстояние между ними. Тут надо выбирать в зависимости от формы предметов.